# unpack lists of list into list with individual items

Tags: python, list

I have a list like:

```
l = [[1,2,3],[4,5]]
```

I would like to unpack each element to make it like:

```
l = [1,2,3,4,5]
```

I have my solution here:

```
l = reduce(lambda x, y: x+y, l)
```

Anyone has other Pythonic way? Thanks.

Comment: Note: your solution is quadratic in time. You shouldn't use it not because it isn't readable, but because it is asymptotically worse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use itertools methods;

```
from itertools import chain

l = [[1,2,3],[4,5]]
list(chain.from_iterable(l))
```

Comment: You're welcome, if this answer is correct you, should close the question; set this answer as your accepted answer. @timchen